# Loading different saves

Tags: state-of-decay

During a defense mission in *State of Decay* my favorite character died, I would rather not lose him. Anyway I can load a previous save as it auto saved on me after his death. I am on Windows and didn't see a load option.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you or can you not load the save?

Comment: @CyberSkull in this game you can only continue not load from what I can tell.

Comment: Are you asking how to load a different save then?

Comment: @CyberSkull "Anyway I can load a previous save "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually backup the save file and replace it, to revert to an earlier stage in the game.

Comment: Any chance you wanna explain in more detail?

Comment: Look for the file Class3.0.ulsave (for profile 1) to Class3.3.ulsave (for profile 3). Usually it's in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\...\local" folder. Put that .ulsave file in a separate folder as backup. When you screw up your game, copy the file from the backup folder and overwrite the one in "local" folder to revert the game to an earlier state.

Comment: Or you can look for a mod that manages save files.